# How do I get the groups belonging to a person ABAddressBook

Tags: iphone, sdk, addressbook

Is there a way to get all groups from the AddressBook belonging to a person without looping through all groups?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it.  It appears [the API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CoreServices/AddressBook/index.html) is written in such a way that it's expected you'll traverse Book -> Groups -> People, not the other way.

Something to ease the pain is [AQToolkit's Contacts API](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master).  To get you out of C-land...

Comment: It is not so much for the pain as for performance reasons. I really want to keep everything slick and tight...
But thx anyway for the link to the API... I only knew about the google toolbox